# Trouble using multiple panels on visual studio

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2012, panels

I'm using visual studio 2012 and i'm finding it extremely difficult(and irritating) to handle multiple panels. I have almost 20 panels stacked on top of each other. I had to make changes to a lower panel so I removed the panels from the top and updated it. Now the lower panel buttons and group boxes keep sticking on all other upper panel buttons and keep covering them.
So basically i can't see half portion of upper panels as the lower panel's controls keep covering 'em up. I don't know what caused this. Please help me out.

Comment: Dock the panels you need, close the ones you don't.  Play around with the docking a bit, you can do it in different ways.  Have you read any of the help topics?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing what your problem looks like it is hard to answer, but since you have multiple panels you probably accidently changed the Parent of some of your controls or panels.

I find that working with layered controls can be a pain, you need to get used to using the `BringToFront` and `SendToBack` Editor Commands.

[image]

To answer your question you can try looking at your `InitializeComponent` Method to see if you can determine exactly what happened.

Comment: Sorry for giving such a vague idea about my problem. Yes actually the parents got mixed up. I fixed it using the document outline window. And "send to back" and "bring to front" seem to be working only on the top two layers.Other layers do get selected but arent visible. Just their outlines are visible through the topmost panel. Could you help me with its usage? And Thank you for your help :) .

Comment: @user3235573 You can find the panel that you wish to work on in your Forms Properties when you select it, it will show the handles by right clicking on one of the handles you can select bring to front. But you also should just be able to keep selecting Send to back until the panel you want is in the forefront.

Comment: What I ended up doing in most of my projects where I was dealing with multiple panels was to create usercontrols instead, exposing the functionality I needed to the program, that way I am able to edit them individually and add them at runtime instead of cluttering up the design time environment.